# Cater varying DateTime formats on the client machines in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, exception

My WPF Application gets certain input from the user in `DateTime` format and updates the corresponding `DateTime` columns in the database with the user input like below

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(weldStatus))
                newFieldJoint.welding_status = Convert.ToDateTime(weldStatus);
```

Above works fine when `DateTime` on the client machine is same as the one on the development machine (i.e. `mm/dd/yyyy`) but if the format on client machine is different lets say `mm/dd/yyyy` then the above throws exception. I believe there can be quite a few different `DateTime` formats. How can I have a generic way to handle this in my application?

P.S: I am using WPF DatePicker control inside DataGrid for getting input from the user like below.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fitup WF">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker Text="{Binding FitupWFDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding FitupWFDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[image: sample exception on the client machine]

Comment: You need to define what formats you allow. There's no way to have it validate all date formats, because not all dates are clear in their meaning. What date is `06/06/2016`? What about `04/05/06` ?

Comment: It's not clear where the data is coming from. If you're taking it directly from the user, use a control which is dedicated to that rather than making the user specify text. If you're passing the value from machine to machine, use a machine-readable standard format such as ISO-8601.

Comment: @Rob, JonSkeet Please see updated question

Comment: Something to do with locale and cultureinfo?

Comment: So where does `weldStatus` come from and why is it a `string` (and why isn't it called `weldDate`, for that matter)? If your client application has obtained a date/time value, it should be passing it as a `DateTime` value to the backend code. If it can't do that, it must pass it as a string in one particular agreed-upon format only. Expecting the backend to do the conversion isn't reasonable because the backend can't know what format the date-as-string is in. Is 01/02/2016 February 1 or January 2?